# Display incremented values from firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to make several buttons almost like a voting system. The user can press 5 different buttons, and the number of votes on each button is stored in Firestore. After on button is pressed, the value is supposed to show up on every button and that's where my problem is. I have made a code that increments the value and shows the number of votes, but it does not work on the button the user pressed. For example, if I press button 1 all the other buttons get their correct number of votes displayed, but on the pressed button only one vote shows up even though it has several votes. This also happens with every other button and the problem only occurs on the pressed button. I am sorry if it's too long, but I am relatively to javascript. Here is my code:

```
            <ul>
              <li class="circleProgressVote"> 
                <button class="btn white black-text voteBtn" id="btn1"  onclick="vote1(); disableButton();"> Svært dårlig </button>
              </li>
              <li class="circleProgressVote">
                <button class="btn white black-text voteBtn" id="btn2"  onclick="vote2(); disableButton();"> Dårlig </button>
              </li>
              <li class="circleProgressVote">
                <button class="btn white black-text voteBtn" id="btn3"  onclick="vote3(); disableButton();"> Usikker </button>
              </li>
              <li class="circleProgressVote">
                <button class="btn white black-text voteBtn" id="btn4"  onclick="vote4(); disableButton();"> Bra </button>
              </li> 
              <li class="circleProgressVote">
                <button class="btn white black-text voteBtn" id="btn5"  onclick="vote5(); disableButton();"> Svært bra </button>
              </li>
            </ul>



function vote1() {
  console.log('ans1');


  const valg1 = db.collection('spørsmål').doc('BdTGAbGw33HSr9GZoJYA');
  valg1.update({ 'valg1': increment });


  db.collection('spørsmål').get().then((snapshot) => {
    snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
      hentSvar1(doc);
    });
  });

  function hentSvar1(doc) {


    let div1 = document.createElement('div');
    let votes1 = document.createElement('span');
    let span1 = document.createElement('span');

    div1.setAttribute('data-id', doc.id);
    votes1.textContent = doc.data().valg1;
    span1.textContent = ' stemmer';

    div1.appendChild(votes1);
    div1.appendChild(span1);

    let div2 = document.createElement('div');
    let votes2 = document.createElement('span');
    let span2 = document.createElement('span');

    div2.setAttribute('data-id', doc.id);
    votes2.textContent = doc.data().valg2;
    span2.textContent = ' stemmer';

    div2.appendChild(votes2);
    div2.appendChild(span2);

    let div3 = document.createElement('div');
    let votes3 = document.createElement('span');
    let span3 = document.createElement('span');

    div3.setAttribute('data-id', doc.id);
    votes3.textContent = doc.data().valg3;
    span3.textContent = ' stemmer';

    div3.appendChild(votes3);
    div3.appendChild(span3);

    let div4 = document.createElement('div');
    let votes4 = document.createElement('span');
    let span4 = document.createElement('span');

    div4.setAttribute('data-id', doc.id);
    votes4.textContent = doc.data().valg4;
    span4.textContent = ' stemmer';

    div4.appendChild(votes4);
    div4.appendChild(span4);

    let div5 = document.createElement('div');
    let votes5 = document.createElement('span');
    let span5 = document.createElement('span');

    div5.setAttribute('data-id', doc.id);
    votes5.textContent = doc.data().valg5;
    span5.textContent = 'stemmer';

    div5.appendChild(votes5);
    div5.appendChild(span5);



    svar1.appendChild(div1);
    svar2.appendChild(div2);
    svar3.appendChild(div3);
    svar4.appendChild(div4);
    svar5.appendChild(div5);


    document.getElementById('btn1').style.border = '2px solid red';

  };
};
```

All the function vote1() - vote5() are the same, without the last line changing the border of the selected button, the increment function on top which increments five different fields in firestore and the function inside is called "hentSvar1", "hentSvar2" and so on. 
I tried using then() after the increment code and just placed in the rest of the code to see if that helps, but that did not work. I also know that the function to show the values are way too long and inefficient, but again I am relatively new to javascript. Here is the database in Firestore if anybody needs it:
[image]
valg1 - valg5 is those fields connected to each button and are the one's updates and shown. 
I am sorry if this is too long, but I can't figure out whats the problem. If any of you could help me I would really appreciate it.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for [update](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#update) states that this method is asynchronous and returns a promise but you're not waiting for the promise to complete before reading the document. This might explain why the values are not updated as expected. I would suggest to add then() and catch() callbacks as  shown in this snippet from the Firestore [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update-data):

```js
var washingtonRef = db.collection("cities").doc("DC");

// Set the "capital" field of the city 'DC'
return washingtonRef.update({
    capital: true
})
.then(function() {
    console.log("Document successfully updated!");
})
.catch(function(error) {
    // The document probably doesn't exist.
    console.error("Error updating document: ", error);
});
```

Separately, there are two things that might not relate to the problem at hand but that might be helpful.

- You're retrieving the whole 'spørsmål' collection even though you just need a single document from it. Given that you know the document Id being used `BdTGAbGw33HSr9GZoJYA` it would be better to just retrieve that document with `db.collection('spørsmål').doc('BdTGAbGw33HSr9GZoJYA').get()`. Check [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document).
- It is the first time that I've seen the syntax `{ fieldname : increment }` instead of `{ fieldname: FieldValue.Increment(number)}` which is the syntax I've found in the [Web API reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldValue#increment). It could be the syntax is correct too since to be fair I'm more used to the Node.js and Python client libraries.

Lastly, you might consider implementing [real-time listeners](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#web) in order to get notified of document changes and thus be sent the new data without the need of querying it yourself. Although it may be kind of overkill for the example at hand it could be useful to simplify some designs approaching the UI updates in a more reactive manner.